# The "android" command is deprecated. Command 'andriod' is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

When I execute the command `android` in **cmd**, am getting below:

```
C:\Users\Admin>android
**************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

I set the android path variables properly, I did some google search and also re-installed my Android Studio, downgraded the platform, but nothing helped me out.

I am using Windows 7 Desktop, Android Studio - 3.5.3

Please guide me.

Comment: There does not appear to be a problem. `android` has been discontinued as a command, and you did not provide any command line options (e.g., `android list target`).

Comment: But my primary interest was to invoke an mobile app using Appium server but this was stopping me from doing that successfully, finally i resolved this issue by downgrading the tools folder in Android/sdk and replaced with this one : https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip , it worked

Comment: That is unlikely to be a good long-term solution.

Comment: Yeah !! but this a temporary solution I found it to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is part of the deprecation warning from the `android` command.

> For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat

- Instead of `$ android < action > avd` use `$ tools\bin\avdmanager.bat < action >`
- Instead of `$ android < action > sdk` use `$ tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat < action >`